# two domain names, one hosting

Tags: dns

my client has registered a domain name on godaddy. He already is hosting a site on smartyhost. Now he wants his godaddy site to point smartyhost site. He does not want a redirect, instead he wants that two different BASE URLs will represent one site. I have read about this but i m confused as there are many solutions and none has worked for me.

For example:

1- Domain forwarding
2- DNS
3- Site mirroring
4- A records
5- Point a domain to another

and many more. I can't understand difference among them all. Can you tell me what is best solution for me and how can i use that solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fairly straight forward. Both domains will resolve to the same IP address. The server at that address will know to serve up the same site for both domains. This is fairly easily configured in Apache and also, I imagine, in most other webservers.

Do note that search engines (notably Google) may penalize you for serving up identical content on multiple domains. It is much preferable to have one domain redirect to the other. Case in point, [del.iciu.us](http://del.iciu.us) redirects to [www.delicious.com](http://www.delicius.com), rather than serving up the same content on both domains.

Comment: I would like to second Kris here in saying that from a SEO standpoint it is not advised to do so. If I were you I would tell your client to add unique content on both websites and use them both as a client funnel. I am sure that he can split his services on two websites - if you are doing SEO and Web Design, throw SEO content on the new domain and use both sites to get clients.

Comment: del.icio.us and delicious.com both points to the same location. I don't see them getting penalized.

Comment: @Mahesh, no, del.iciu.us and delicious.com both redirect to www.delicius.com

Answer (score 0):

I have a client who wanted about eight different domain names to point to the same website. I could not do this due to SEO, aka the ranking of the website. I did notice that when I had all of the domains redirect to the same site, the ranking dropped off significantly.

If you would like to do what you are asking, ere should be a configuration page with the network host(s) that allows for domain forwarding to the same IP. I know for sure this is the case with Network Solutions, I am not sure about Godaddy however.

Comment: Doing it at the server level with a 301 redirect shouldn't have messed with your rankings. How did you do the redirects?